# What is the best way to handle errors in 68000 assembly language?

Tags: assembly, 68000

I've been writing a lot of 68K assembly language, recently, and I've noticed a pattern, roughly the following:

```
do_something:
    movem.l d2-d5/a2-a3,-(sp)

    ...
    jsr     xxx
    tst.l   d0
    beq     open_error

    ...
    jsr     yyy
    tst.l   d0
    bmi     read_error

    ...
    move.l  #ERR_OKAY,d0
    bra     exit

open_error:
    move.l  #ERR_OPEN,d0
    bra     exit

read_error:
    move.l  #ERR_READ,d0

exit:
    movem.l (sp)+,d2-d5/a2-a3
    rts
```

That is, I have a lot of branches to instructions that just set a return code then branch to some clean-up instructions.

Is there some clever way to do this more efficiently, or am I just doing what needs to be done?

The only optimization I've been able to come up with is to save a branch on the most-common (no error) path:

```
    ...
    move.l  #ERR_OKAY,d0

exit:
    movem.l (sp)+,d2-d5/a2-a3
    rts

open_error:
    move.l  #ERR_OPEN,d0
    bra     exit

read_error:
    move.l  #ERR_READ,d0
    bra     exit
```

Comment: You could use a jump table if you have a good index - put all the jump labels into a table, use the index of the error to read the address from the table, then jump/call that routine.  This is what C compilers generally do for switch statements.

Comment: I'd say you are just doing what needs to be done.  It's similar in C and Go code.

Comment: Basically you are just doing what needs to be done. There are different ways of doing it, as @MichaelDorgan explains, but yours is the simplest.

Comment: Are you open to refinement of the calling convention?  For example, you might forgo the `tst d0.l` if you guarantee to set the condition codes by the return value in the callee.

Comment: What do you intend to improve? Runtime? Code size? Binary size? Readability? Are you providing `do_something` for others to call (i.e., are you bound to that interface?) or is it only called by functions which you control?

Comment: It's a 40-year-old microprocessor, so I'm just programming it for fun, and to learn how it works. do_something is called by my other code, but the JSR's are to OS library routines, so I'm stuck with how they work. Mainly, I'm looking for readability. Whenever I see a pattern, I think "subrountine" (or macro). I suppose I want a compare-set-and-branch instruction. In a HLL, I'd "if (error) return ERR_OPEN", which is succinct. I'm thinking I just need to accept the verbosity as the reason why people developed HLL's.

Comment: What you are asking for is a code review and you should be asking such questions on the [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) Please delete this and ask over there. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

If you have to (or choose to) obey the ABI you are currently using (return error code in `d0`, and have registers `d2-d7/a2-a6` preserved), there is not much you can do.

In some special cases you might micro-optimize certain operations, e.g., if `ERR_OPEN` happens to be `-1` (and you can handle a modified `d0`), you could replace:

```
    tst.l   d0
    beq     open_error

...
open_error:
    move.l  #ERR_OPEN,d0
    bra     exit
```

By:

```
    subq.l  #1,d0
    bcs     exit    ; carry is only set if `d0` was 0 before
```

And if you want to optimize for speed instead of code-size, you could replace all

```
    bra     exit
```

by the corresponding

```
    movem.l (sp)+,d2-d5/a2-a3
    rts
```

---

If you do have more liberties on the interface, you could just say "my function may destroy registers `d0-d5/a0-a3` and let the caller handle that (and all `bra exit` would become a single `rts`).

Also, especially if your function was called from just a single other function, which itself checks `d0` directly after calling it, you could simply 'inline' your function and directly branch to the code which actually handles each error (but for bigger functions this will likely make just a negligible improvement at the cost of much poorer readability).

And if your main concern is the verbosity, I'd really suggest porting this to a higher level language (and only hand-optimize performance critical functions -- if you can actually implement them better than your compiler).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I'm writing this on a Commodore Amiga 500. Some of it is my code; other is system calls. I'm following the OS conventions because they make sense re a good compromise between caller save vs callee save. The reason for `bra exit` over `rts` is to have a single point to restore registers and do any other clean up.

Comment: Actually, I wrote  the program in C first, and I'm porting it to assembly language. My main goals are to learn 68000 assembly language and to make the program easy to undertand.

Comment: Yes, if "easy to understand" is the main goal, I'd avoid any of my suggestions (e.g., copying the `movem` to multiple exit points will fail if you ever need to change more registers and forget to adapt one exit point). And your assembler will hopefully optimize `move.l #x,d0` to a `moveq` where this is possible.